# Unable to establish SSL connection while setting up SSL on Ubuntu/Apache2

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl

```
    root@www:/etc/apache2# wget https://www.domainname.com
--2013-09-19 09:15:12--  https://www.domainname.com/
Resolving www.classmint.com (www.domainname.com)... 198.*.124.142
Connecting to www.domainname.com (www.domainname.com)|198.*.124.142|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

If I put Listen 443 in ports.conf, i can't restart apache.

I am able to access http://domainname.com:443 but i can't use https. What could be wrong?

What are best ways to troubleshoot this?

Comment: you have to define a ssl settings for apache base on the location where to stablish the https connection, if from virtualhost or while redirecting to another directory.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you http://www.ssl.ua/news/how-to-create-and-install-an-apache-self-signed-certificate/
And you need to install SSL "apt-get install libssl-dev"